# System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine in windows azure

Tags: azure, system.diagnostics

When I use System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine in my Azure development, how long is that information stored.
Does it get wiped out when a worker role or web role is recycled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Windows Azure Diagnostics to push that data on a schedule to table storage, it's stored forever (until you delete it).

If you're not pushing the data to storage, it lives until the circular buffer fills up on the local disk or the role instance is restarted.

If you're not running Diagnostics at all, then it just disappears into the ether. :)